# Cannot access C++ extension module and its methods from python created using SWIG

Tags: python, c++, swig

Created an empty c++ in `visual studio 2017`
added the following files with following C++ methods

//gfg.c

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h> 

//our header file 
#include "gfg.h" 
#define ll long long 

double myvar = 3.4;

// calculate factorial 
ll int fact(ll int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return (n * fact(n - 1));
}

//find mod 
int my_mod(int n, int m)
{
    return(n % m);
}
```

//gfg.h

```
#pragma once

long long int fact(long long int n);
int my_mod(int n, int m);
```

//gfg.i  for swig

```
/* file : gfg.i */

/* name of module to use*/
%module gfg 
%{ 
    /* Every thing in this file is being copied in  
     wrapper file. We include the C header file necessary 
     to compile the interface */
    #include "gfg.h" 

    /* variable declaration*/
    double myvar; 
%} 

/* explicitly list functions and variables to be interfaced */
double myvar; 
long long int fact(long long int n1); 
int my_mod(int m, int n); 

/* or if we want to interface all functions then we can simply 
   include header file like this -  
   %include "gfg.h" 
*/
```

Added custom action for gfg.i file as below with output file name as gfg_wrap.c

```
$(SWIG_PATH)\swig.exe -python gfg.i
```

while compiling gfg.i file, it given two outputs `gfg.py` and `gfg_wrap.c`.

then i created `Setup.py` file with the following contents

```
# File : setup.py 

from distutils.core import setup, Extension 
#name of module 
name  = "gfg"

#version of module 
version = "1.0"

# specify the name of the extension and source files 
# required to compile this 
ext_modules = Extension(name='_gfg',sources=["gfg.i","gfg.c"]) 

setup(name=name, 
      version=version, 
      ext_modules=[ext_modules]) 

#C:\Python37\python_d.exe setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

with custom action as

```
C:\Python37\python_d.exe setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

this python directory contains swig.exe

after executing this, it generated an `_gfg_d.cp37-win_amd64.pyd` file in the project directory.

when given `import gfg` from CMD it shown the following error.

[image]

I was trying to access `fact` method from `gfg.h` Is there something iam missing out?

Comment: Looks like you've built it for a Python interpreter that's different to the one you're actually running. I can't quite see how from what's written though.  Maybe something to do with the python_d.exe being not your system's default Python.

Comment: python37.dll is used by a Release build of Python, but you're trying to use a Debug build of Python, which is looking for python37_d.dll instead.  Run it with `python.exe` for Python 3.7 and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

python37.dll is used by a Release build of Python, but you're trying to use a Debug build of Python, which is looking for python37_d.dll instead.  Run it with `python.exe` for Python 3.7 and it will work.

If you want a debug build, use:

```
setup.py build_ext --debug --inplace
```

The name of the extension will be `_gfg.cp37-win_amd64.pyd` (or some variation on another platform).  It must be named `_gfg.pyd` for a release version or `_gfg_d.pyd` for a debug version.  I had to manually rename it to get it to work. 
 I didn't find an option to force the name:

```
C:\>copy _gfg.cp37-win_amd64.pyd _gfg_d.pyd
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\>python_d
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 05:02:23) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gfg
>>> gfg.fact(5)
120
```